# Deep Sleep NodeMCU with Door Sensor

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I have a very simple code of door sensor (magnetic) which gives results in 1 & 0 format. But I want to run the NodeMCU only when a door is open or close. Rest of time I want to keep it in deep sleep mode. Here is my code looks like :

```
int doorClosed = 1;

#define REED_SWITCH D5

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);

  pinMode(REED_SWITCH, INPUT_PULLUP); 
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly

   Serial.println(digitalRead(REED_SWITCH));

    if ((digitalRead(REED_SWITCH) == HIGH) && (doorClosed == 1))
    {
      Serial.println("DOOR OPEN!!");
      doorClosed = 0;
      digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);
      ESP.deepSleep(0); 
    } 
    else if ((digitalRead(REED_SWITCH) == LOW) && (doorClosed == 0))
    {
      Serial.println("DOOR CLOSED!!");
      doorClosed = 1;
      digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);
      ESP.deepSleep(0); 
    }
    delay(500);
}
```

Here I am able to put the NodeMCU in deep sleep. But it never wakes up. How can I wake up my chip. After attaching the D0 with RST, I don't event get Serial Logs. I am not sure what kind of behaviour is this. If someone can help me to fix this code will be great!

Thank you!

Comment: According to this guide (https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-deep-sleep-with-arduino-ide/) the pin to be connected to RST is D0 and not A0.

Comment: I am sorry it was a typo mistake. I just fixed it.

Comment: After going in sleep mode, check D0 voltage value with a multimeter. Should be approximately to 0V.

Comment: If D0 is not 0V, connect RST to GND and check if microcontroller wakes up.

Comment: I just check the D0 voltage, but seems like its not going to 0V its showing me 3.25V. Which means its not going to deep sleep? 

in multimeter I am touching D0 and GND pin to check the voltage.

Comment: Before investigating why D0 is high, try to connect GND to RST pin e check if arduino wakes up. ESP8266 documentation says that is sufficient a low value on RST pin to wakes up.

Comment: @leoc7 yes it was waking it up. But i am not able to see any details in serial monitor, so not sure how can i do that.

Comment: You can’t see any details on serial monitor because esp8266 restarts program and you have to re-open serial monitor. Use a led instead print on serial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [guide](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-deep-sleep-with-arduino-ide/):

> The RST pin of the ESP8266 is always HIGH while the ESP8266 is
>   running. However, when the RST pin receives a LOW signal, it restarts
>   the microcontroller.
>
> If you set a **Deep Sleep timer** with the ESP8266, once the timer ends,
>   GPIO 16 sends a LOW signal. That means that GPIO 16 when connected to
>   RST pin can wake up the ESP8266 every time the timer ends.

The only way to wakes up ESP8266 from deep sleep mode **without timer** is set a LOW signal on RST pin.

Example without timer:

```
ESP.deepSleep(0);
```

Connect D0 (GPIO 16) to RST is available only when ESP8266 is in sleep mode **with timer**.

Example with 30sec timer:

```
ESP.deepSleep(30e6);
```

In your case, you can use deep sleep with timer and connect Door sensor to D0 and will act as switch between the RST and D0.

Comment: can i do that programmatically?

Comment: also if its in deep sleep mode. Then how can i send a signal to it? i am using door sensor, will it be able to read its value in deep sleep?

Comment: You can’t do it programmatically! During deep sleep esp8266 is switched off and can’t do any operation. An approach can be to set a deep sleep mode with timer (e.g. 30sec) and connect D0 to RST. Every 30sec esp8266 wakes up, restart program and check door sensor.

Comment: interrupt will also not work in this case?

Comment: No, if you use Deep Sleep, ESP8266 is off and the only way to wake up it is trigger physically RST pin. Consider to use other type of sleep mode (for example light-sleep)

Take a look to this guide: https://www.losant.com/blog/making-the-esp8266-low-powered-with-deep-sleep

Comment: OK if I use door sensor then? Because door sensor can work externally on door open and close. As I want to connect with door sensor.

Comment: I got it working! Door sensor can be connected to D0 and will act as switch between the RST and D0. With this try. I am able to get it fixed. If you want you can post it under answer I will mark it right. :)

Comment: I modified the answer :) If you want you can mark as resolved.

Comment: i got it resolved upto a certain limit. The thing is i am able to restart it by setting the value high, but on closing door i don't get it restarted, so there is some challenge now

Answer (score 0):

My response is late but herewith my experience that may be of help to others.

NodeMcu in deep sleep will wake-up from external source on receiving a pulse from high to low on the RST pin.

An ADXL345 accelerometer raises an interrupt HIGH on sensing motion and remains high until (I2C) READ to prevent multiple devices from interfering with each other

The following post was instrumental in my finding a solution

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/158015/how-to-turn-continuous-signal-into-a-short-pulse-using-logic-gates